# how to display Facebook audience network in-stream video ads?

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network

I want to display Facebook In-stream video ads to my Android app

[please see red square part of this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVS40.png)

currently I`m following this doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-instream
and it says like this : "Then, go to the "Apply for in-stream video ads" section."

but when I go to "App Dashboard" and click "Audience Network" , I really can`t find "Apply for in-stream video ads section"

I can't see any kind of those items when I click on the Audience Network button.
Can anyone help me please? I really would appreciate it thank you for reading

Comment: Hi Fantômas,

Did you get any solution to this problem? I also wanted to show video ads in my Expo app, but finding it difficult to get anything from these docs